# Can't change service folder name

Tags: service, task

I am trying to rename a folder inside "inetpub/wwwroot/Services" folder. An error windows rises with message "the action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program". The insider program is executed only by a scheduled task which is active and ready but not running.
How to proceed?

Comment: Hello Juniel. Welcome to stack overflow.   Could you provide some technical data in your question.  For instance, how are you trying to rename the folder? Are you using a manual method, powershell, c# etc.   Also can you clarify  what you mean by "insider program". that would be helpful if you could add some more technical details in the question.   Questions need to be as clear as possible. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I resolved it. The folder was open by another user remotely connected to the computer.
Just got to close his session and Voilá!